# Viewing Entire XML packets with WSDL Proxy Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl

All,
I have this SOAP web service, the way I do it is generated a WSDL proxy class based on the WSDL file (using the wsdl tool from Microsoft). Now, I want to also have the ability to log the ENTIRE XML packets, both outbound and inbound. I know that there's a class called SOAPExtension to overwrite. But for ppl like me using the WSDL proxy class, how to we even hook into the SOAPExtension class since that proxy class is supposed to be make the call...? Can anyone help?

Regards,
Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use WSE2, you can put this in your web.config, in `<microsoft.web.services2>` section:

```
<diagnostics>
  <trace enabled="true" input="InputTrace.log" output="OutputTrace.log" />
</diagnostics>
```

You will see the incoming xml in "InputTrace.log" and outcoming in "OutputTrace.log", both files in the root directory of your app.

EDIT: There must be a simple way like this if you're *not* using WSE, but I'm not aware of, so anyone feel free to add your two cents...